# De Morgan's saying: "I was x years old in the year x^2"

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Augustus de Morgan, when asked about his age, remarked:

> I was $x$ years old in the year $x^2$.

He died in $1871$. Examining possible squares, we find
$41^2 = 1681$, $42^2 = 1764$, $43^2 = 1849$, $44^2 = 1936$. Clearly, the only one which makes sense in this problem would be $43^2 = 1849$. So de Morgan was $43$ in $1849$. Therefore, he was born in $1806$.

Is there a systematic way to answer such a question without trial and error?

Comment: He was $0$ years old in the year $x^2-x=x(x-1)$

Comment: isn't this absurd, He said this when obviously he was alive so you shouldn't know when he will die and use that to find his age !? or I misunderstood something ?

Comment: @DavoodKarimi A contemporary of de Morgan would only go up to the year he said this. But that information is not (readily) available to us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The year is $x^2$ and he died in 1871. Assuming he lived less than 100 years:

$1871-100<x^2<1871$

Taking the square root of both sides
$42\le x\le44$ .

Still need trial and error, but there are only 3 candidates.

Comment: Thank you very much. Clever solution:-)!

Comment: When you take the square root, you have to round the result towards the right direction: if he was born in 1771, then there's no way his mystery age could be 42, because $42^2 = 1764 < 1771$. Same thing for 44. So only 43 remains.